# How can I exclude %TEMP% and %TMP% directories from user profile disk in Remote Desktop Services

Tags: group-policy, remote-desktop-services, user-profile, google-chrome, systempath

We are trying to deploy extensions for Chrome using GPOs. Due to Chrome not supporting junction points, we cannot do this when using user profile disks as they have no drive letter when dereferencing a path within the disk.

We are trying to get around this by excluding the TEMP and TMP directories from the user profile disk, but any variation I have tried in the Remote Desktop Configuration for our collection (We are using RD 2012 R2 deployment), does not seem to work.

We have successfully tested using a logon script to manually change the two environment variables to elsewhere within C:\, but I want to avoid scripting if we don't have to use it, and I am never keen on messing with default environment variables in case other apps have conflicts with this.

Can anyone advise how I can successfully exclude the temp directories from a UPD using the normal collection configuration rather than scripting?

Answer (score 0):

Our solution was to change UPD settings from "Include all data", to "Only include selected data".

This way, rather than attempting to exclude folders we didn't want, we simply include folders we do want. By default, appdata\local and all sub directories are excluded, meaning the temp folder is also excluded, allowing us to do what we want to do.